# How to determine font-size for SVG element?

Tags: google-chrome, svg, font-size

I am not sure how SVG computes the rendered font size for a text element.  I would like to theoretically calculate what will be font-size for a text element.

And then, I would like to verify what the actual font-size is using Chrome tools.

The following is an example.  Firstly, the SVG header:

```
<svg  id="svdid-ta" viewBox="430.73 1440.1 705.52 987" width="175" height ="244.82" >
```

I understand that the ratio of the viewBox sizes is about 4.03 (705.52 / 175) so I am expecting the actual font size to scaled down by this amount.

Here is the text element:

```
<text id = "TEXT_NAME" x = "430.73" y = "1486.1" font-size = "36px">Test Text</text>
```

As expected, the actual font size which is rendered is considerably smaller than the 36px.

But I would like to find out what was the **precise** font size which was rendered.

Chrome reports in the computed tab, that the font-size is 36 px. This is clearly wrong as the actual rendered font is very small.

So, my question is how do I actually calculate the theoretical font-size, such that I can know in advance what size the rendered font will be...?

And then, how (using Chrome tools) how do I verify what the actual font-size is..?

Answer (score 2):

Your SVG coordinate system is being scaled down to fit the specified width and height (175 x 244.82).  That's why the font is smaller.

Luckily your viewBox and your width/height have the same aspect ratio, so determining the exact scaling is trivial.  It is just `width / viewBox.width` (or `height / viewBox.height`).

```
width / viewBox.width = 175 / 705.52 = 0.248
```

So, assuming there are no other transforms affecting it, your final text size should be:

```
36px * 0.248 = 8.9px
```

As for how to verify this with Chrome tools, I don't think you can.

Comment: for exact caluculation for all cases you have to consider preserveAspectRatio as well.  
for the default value of "xMidYMid meet"
the formula would be `36px * min(width / viewBox.width , height / viewBox.height)`
for "none" you would have different x and y scale and so no direct mapping to a font-size... you see if you want to get it right for all cases it will be a bit more complicatete, but in principle this answer is correct.

Comment: @HolgerWill As I pointed out in my answer, the aspect ratios of the SVG and the viewBox are the same, so in this case the value of preserveAspectRatio doesn't matter.

Comment: yep, i just wanted to point out, that with the formula  `36px * min(width / viewBox.width , height / viewBox.height)` you can cover all cases where width / height ratio is different, as long as you keep preserveAspectRatio untouched.

Answer (score 0):

ok, here is how you calculate the resulting fontsize for all possible cases of preseveAspectRatio:

the align paramater doesn't matter. So for "meet"(which is the default) you need:

```
Scale =  min(width / viewBox.width , height / viewBox.height)
```

for "slice" :

```
Scale = max(width / viewBox.width , height / viewBox.height)
```

and for "none":

```
scaleX = width / viewBox.width
scaleY = height / viewBox.height
```